# Trouble understanding the definition of irrelevant ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

> In mathematics, the irrelevant ideal is the ideal of a graded ring
> generated by the homogeneous elements of degree greater than zero.
> More generally, a homogeneous ideal of a graded ring is called an
> irrelevant ideal if its radical contains the irrelevant ideal.

Say $R=k[x,y]$. Then irrelevant ideal is an ideal generated by $x,y,x^2,y^2,xy, \cdots$. Is this correct?

Comment: Boy, I do not think it was a good decision to define what “the” irrelevant ideal is, and then proceed to define what “other irrelevant ideals” are in terms of it. Seems like a job for a separate term.

Comment: I think what you wrote seems correct according to that definition.

Comment: One small thing - you have not defined a grading on your ring. If you're using a grading where $x$ and $y$ have positive degree, then you are correct, otherwise something else may happen. (I also agree with rschwieb's comment about the terminology.)